# Property 'RelativeTimeFormat' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'

Tags: typescript

There are no errors while writing the code, but this occurs during compilation:

```
src/index.ts:2:24 - error TS2339: Property 'RelativeTimeFormat' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl'.

2   const rtf = new Intl.RelativeTimeFormat("en", { style: "long" });
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

Although this problem should have been solved after [**this PR**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/36084).

My **tsconfig**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "lib": [
      "DOM",
      "ESNext"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

TypeScript version: **4.0.3**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the PR you linked, it was only published with TypeScript v4.1.2. Also, it is part of the `es2020.intl` TypeScript lib definition.

You first need to install a more up to date version of typescript: `npm install -D typescript@^4.1.2

Then you must update your tsconfig with something like:

```json
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "lib": [
    "DOM",
    "ES2020",
    "ESNext"
    ],
  ...
}
```

---

Another solution would be to use a polyfill instead. This will ensure that your React application works in older browser not supporting the ES2020 standard.
See here https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-relativetimeformat/

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up [Intl.RelativeTimeFormat](https://formatjs.io/docs/polyfills/intl-relativetimeformat/) polyfill provided by **Format.JS**

**Usage**

**Via polyfill.io**

You can use polyfill.io URL Builder to create a polyfill script tag for Intl.RelativeTimeFormat. By default the created URL does not come with any locale data. In order to add locale data, append Intl.RelativeTimeFormat.~locale. to your list of features. For example:

```
<!-- Polyfill Intl.RelativeTimeFormat, its dependencies & `en` locale data -->
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.RelativeTimeFormat,Intl.RelativeTimeFormat.~locale.en"></script>
```

**Simple**

```
import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill'
import '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/en' // locale-data for en
```

**Dynamic import + capability detection**

```
import {shouldPolyfill} from '@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/should-polyfill'
async function polyfill(locale: string) {
  const unsupportedLocale = shouldPolyfill(locale)
  // This locale is supported
  if (!unsupportedLocale) {
   return
  }
  // Load the polyfill 1st BEFORE loading data
  await import('@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill-force')
  await import(
  `@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale- 
  data/${unsupportedLocale}`
  )
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33535489)