# Property Locale does not exist on type of Intl?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm copying this directly from the MDN Web Docs:

```js
const korean = new Intl.Locale('ko', {
  script: 'Kore',
  region: 'KR',
  hourCycle: 'h24',
  calendar: 'gregory',
});

const japanese = new Intl.Locale('ja-Jpan-JP-u-ca-japanese-hc-h12');

console.log(korean.baseName, japanese.baseName);
// expected output: "ko-Kore-KR" "ja-Jpan-JP"

console.log(korean.hourCycle, japanese.hourCycle);
// expected output: "h24" "h12"
```

But am getting the aforementioned error: Property 'Locale' does not exist on typeof Intl.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context if you want help. Where are you using this?

Comment: This sounds like a TypeScript error.

Comment: Did you see this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64333204/property-relativetimeformat-does-not-exist-on-type-typeof-intl

Comment: @pilchard Just in one of my functional components. Unless it needs to be placed somewhere else for some reason. Trying to test out standardizing locales as it turns out some browsers want to return "en-us" rather than "en-US", for example.

Comment: This now works with Chrome 98 and later. It was not supported earlier.